# FFMPEG Downgrade Only If 4k Video and Keep Aspect Ratio

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to downgrade video resolutions if and only if they are above a certain resolution?

For example, right now I am doing to:

```
ffmpeg -i 4k_VIdeo.MP4 -vf scale=1920:1080 -c:v libx264 -crf 35 1080-video-smaller.mp4
```

But if the video is 720:600 or a smaller resolution, I don't want to expand to 1920, also if the video is not the aspect ratio of 1920:1080, I want to keep the same aspect ratio so it doesn't look distorted.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i 4k_video.mp4 \
-filter_complex \ 
"scale='if(gt(iw,1920),1920,-1)':'if(gt(ih,1080),1080,-1)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 35 1080-video-smaller.mp4
```

The following command sets the scale width to 1920 if the original input width is higher than 1920, otherwise it sets it to -1 which will automatically choose the width to maintain the original aspect ratio. Same for height with 1080.
In case both width and height are larger, the resolution will be 1920x1080, though the `force_original_aspect_ratio` will decrease the width or the height if the aspect ratio doesn't match.

- iw: input width
- ih: input height
- gt: greater than